# C - Comparing char with string

Tags: c, string, char

I know that the values of both char "c" and 2-D string array "stringArray[0][0]" are both "0" and equal. However, I'm having trouble comparing them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

char c = '0';
const char *stringArray[2][2] = {"0","1"},{"2","3"};

printf("%d\n",c); // prints 0
printf("%s\n",stringArray[0][0]); // prints 0

if(c == stringArray[0][0][0]){ // compiler threw an error with stringArray[0][0]
    printf("Success!\n"); // does not print success
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code emits compile error. I think `{"0","1"},{"2","3"}` should be `{{"0","1"},{"2","3"}}`.

Comment: `'0'` (character code) and `0` (zero) isn't equal since character code 0 is null character in C language. `printf("%d\n",c);` doesn't print 0 but instead print 48 and Success! is printed with the correction above.

Comment: Shoudn't you compare c == stringArray[0][0] instead of c == stringArray[0][0][0] ?

Comment: @wojjas No, you shouldn't. `c` is a number and `stringArray[0][0]` is a pointer. Compareing these doesn't make sense.

Comment: If stringArray[0][0] is a pointer how come printf("%s\n",stringArray[0][0]); // prints 0? It seems to me  stringArray[0][0][0] is like treating  stringArray[0][0] as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it explains everything:)

```
printf("%d\n", stringArray[0][0]);
printf("%d\n", '0');
printf("%d\n", stringArray[0][0][0]);
printf("%d\n", *stringArray[0][0]);

./a.out
182304636
48
48
48
```

Try this as well

```
if('0' == *stringArray[0][0]){ 
    printf("Success!\n"); 
}

./a.out
Success!
```

Comment: You have the incorrect format specifier on the first line so it will invoke undefined behavior. Should be `%p`.

Comment: my basic concern was to demonstrate that stringArray[0][0] points address and to specific value, which you correctly pointed out.. 
if value needs to be compared additional [0] is needed or *stringArray[0][0]

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the compiler error with the initializer list (add two braces), it works just fine. Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

  char c = '0';
  const char *stringArray[2][2] = {{"0","1"},{"2","3"}};

  printf("%d\n",c); // prints 48
  printf("%s\n",stringArray[0][0]);

  if(c == stringArray[0][0][0]){
      printf("Success!\n");
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Output as expected:

```
48
0
Success!
```